# send-mail.php only send field if the field exists

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a form being posted to send-mail.php  The form field is generated dynamically, sometimes it will exist, sometimes it will not exist.  I want the email received to only contain the form field if it exists, if the form field does not exist there should be nothing in the email about.  The code below always indicates "null" whether the field exists or not. Any ideas?

```
$myBlueTextArea = isset($_POST['sender_BlueText']);
if($myBlueTextArea) print 'not null';
if(!$myBlueTextArea) print 'null';
```

Comment: Is this field a checkbox? checkbox inputs are NOT send back to the server unless they've actually been checked. if it isn't a checkbox, then have you done any basic debugging, e.g. `var_dump($_POST)` to see if you're spelling things correctly?

Answer (score 0):

How I usually do this is with a generic processor for forms. Basically, name the form fields what you would like them to display as in the email and then create an email based on that. Usually I separate words with dashes so I use something like the following:

```
$body = 'You got a form submission! <br />';
foreach($_POST as $name => $value)
{
    $name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-z0-9]/', '', $name);
    $body .= "<strong> $name </strong>: $value <br />";
}
```

This way all posted fields are stored in the `$body` variable in a somewhat formatted way, change the markup to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The code below is how I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is how I solved the problem.  You can test it by filling out the form as-is and sending/emailing it to yourself, then comment out the Message textarea field and re-submit the form. When that field does not exist, the email that the form sends will omit that field instead of sending the message field as null or empty, etc.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "johndoe@xmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";

        if(isset($_POST['message'])){
            $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
        }

    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Form submission</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```